# how to fill bed number column for patients table in a hospital database according to the occupied dates of a particular bed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am working on a hospital database for my project. I have the tables patient, bed, doctor and so on. The patient table and the bed table has Beg_Date and End_Date for which the patient is admitted and the bed is occupied respectively.

I want to fill the `bed_No` column in `patient` table with an empty bed number (i.e if the bed is not occupied by any patient). The problem i have is that i only have 300 beds for 500 patients. Therefore i am totally unsure how to fill the bed numbers by comparing the `Beg_Date` and `End_Date` of patients. i also want this information to be saved inside the bed table under `patientID`, `Beg_Date` and `End_Date` columns (i.e information on which patient has occupied which bed for which dates). For this bed table i only know there is a "On Insert Cascade" and "On delete cascade" but unsure how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also work for a hospital.

You absolutely do not want to put bed data in your patient table.  Bed data is part of a visit, not part of a person.  First, patients may have multiple visits.  Also, if your hospital is like mine, patients can change beds during their visit.  Transfers between Critical Care and normal nursing units are common.

If your hospital is putting 500 people into 300 beds, find out how that's happening in real life and design your database accordingly.

**Edit starts here**

Based on Jason's comments, you could have a bed occupancy table plus a bed table.  Then your available beds would be something like:

```
select bed_id
from bed
minus
select bed_id
from bed_occupancy
where enter_datetime is not null
and departure_datetime is null
```

Then it would be up to a user to assign patients to empty beds.  In real life there are other considerations such as some beds are on surgical wards, some in critical care, etc.  The clinical staff are more effective when they have short walks between their patients.

Comment: Based on that, it sounds like he could have a bridge table between patients and beds that had its own effective dates, to reflect when a patient was actually in a given bed.

Comment: It would be between visits and dates.  If Buddy gets admitted, discharged, and admitted again, that's one patient with two visits.

Comment: like Jason said i have a bridge table between bed and patient. i want to populate this table with patientID, bedID, status(available/occupied), Beg_Date and End_Date (if occupied)...sorry if the question was confusing...pls help thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Add an extra colum, called as **bed_status** and have some predefined statuses like, **available, occupied, reserved** etc.

Irrespective of the patients, consider only the bed number as ur unique id.

update this particular bed table whenever a patient is admitted or discharged or even if in some critical cases transferred.

Note- If possible assign the patient number to that particular bed number. similarly update the both when patient is discharged or admitted.

Just run the query based on status to find the occupied beds, available beds and reserved beds etc.

**SELECT COUNT(bed_status) AS availableBeds FROM bed_table WHERE bed_status = 'Available'**

**SELECT COUNT(bed_status) AS occupiedBeds FROM bed_table WHERE bed_status = 'Occupied'**

**SELECT COUNT(bed_status) AS reservedBeds FROM bed_table WHERE bed_status = 'Reserved'**

Comment: Yes, but i did not use the COUNT to find the bed_status instead i used your explanation to write a different query and it works....thank you

Comment: Cheers..!! glad it worked for u..! plzz do ping me for any further assistance u need, its my pleasure helping u..!:)